# iOS - how do I redirect to a new screen from the controller?

Tags: ios, ios5

I have been mapping user flow from screen to screen using the storbyboard, but now I have a need to programmatically redirect the user from one controller to another.

I tried to look up how to do that, but I am not finding much, partially because I am not sure how to word this correctly :)

I know in Android it is as simple as creating a new Intent object and telling it which other screen to go to..but how do I do this in iOS?

Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out the UIStoryboard class.

Try creating the new controller using - (id)instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier from the main Storyboard.

You can then use the new view controller as you would normally.

[EDIT]

```
LoginController *loginController = [[UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MainStoryboard" bundle:nil] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginController"];

[self presentModalViewController:loginController animated:YES];
```

You need to give your LoginController the Identifier of "LoginController".

"MainStoryboard" is the default name for the main storyboard.

[EDIT]
The name of the main storyboard is listed in your plist file as "Main storyboard file base name" (UIMainStoryboardFile).

To set the Identifier of the LoginController:
If you are looking at the storyboard in xcode select the "Login Controller" view controller (shown under the Login Controller Scene) show the attributes inspector found in the Utilities pane (right hand side pane) and under the View Controller section you will see the Identifier field. Set this to "LoginController" - for the example above

Comment: I am not certain how to know or assign the id of the ViewController I want to go to...how do I do that? Thanks!

Comment: edited answer to include info about setting the Identifier of the LoginController ^

Comment: thanks, I followed your instructions, but I still get a compile error in my Objective c code that I have use of undeclared identifier loginController.  Am I am supposed to declare it in the header of the .h and the .m controller which will be executing the code and linking to the LoginController ?  Thanks!

Comment: I added #import "LoginController.h" to my .m file and now I am able to compile. But I get a build error...some linking error that is long and I don't understand :) researching it now :)

Comment: Have you added #import "LoginController.h" to the view controller you're doing this in?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/14205/discussion-between-errolc-and-geekedout)

Comment: I get these errors now: Undefined symbols for architecture i386:
  "_stringIsNumeric", referenced from:
      ___30-[ViewController sendFeedback]_block_invoke_0 in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture i386
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like this, I ran in to this same problem a while ago and this is what I used.

```
[self presentModalViewController:yourviewController animated:YES]
```

Comment: S I am trying to do something like this [self presentModalViewController:LoginController animated:YES] ..in my case it is the LoginController ...but obviously I can't just name it like that...what is the right syntax in my case?

Answer (score 1):

If the target controller is in your storyboard, create a named segue between the two controllers.  When you need to move from one to the other, use `performSegueWithIdentifier:sender:` .  (See UIViewController docs on that method for details.)

Comment: thanks, I just made a segue in the storyboard, but I am blanking a bit on how to make the segue named. How do I actually do that? :)

Comment: Select the segue itself, go to the Attributes inspector (top right), and fill in the Identifier field.